# OpenCV find image frequencies

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, dft

I am trying to find the dominant frequencies in an image using OpenCV. I saw the dft example in the OpenCV tutorial but how can I find the dominant frequencies of an image with periodic structures? I want to extract the spectral informations of the lowest harmonics, copy them to a new image and do reverse dft. A sample image is attached to this question.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the context of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to remove the periodic structures of the images so that there are only the non periodic parts left. My idea is: Find periodic image information (using dft)->remove periodic information from image (maybe substract)->have an image without the periodic lines (see above) but with the small non periodic structures.