# Python/OpenCV: How can I infer an optimal structuring element from image data?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a sample of **two-dimensional**, black-and-white/binary barcodes that have been photographed.

The (colour) photographs typically suffer from all the usual suspects: blurring, distortion, contrast issues/lighting gradients, and erosion.

I am trying to reconstruct the original barcodes, which were once computer-generated pixel arrays of black/white values.

We should be able to exploit the images' spatial-frequency information to infer the dimensions of each pixel. The hope is to use this to better restore the original by convolving the image with such a structuring element defined by the data.

Although this is a very broad topic, I therefore have a very specific question:

***What is the best way to establish a structuring element from image data in OpenCV/Python, without using prior knowledge of it?***

(Assume for now that the underlying pixel scale is to some good approximation spatially invariant)

Note that I am not trying to execute the whole extraction pipeline: this question is simply about inferring an optimal structuring element from the data.

For example, the spatial kernel could be used as input to an unsharp mask, a la [Python unsharp mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454613/python-unsharp-mask)

**References:**

(1-D ideas) http://answers.opencv.org/question/174384/how-to-reconstruct-damaged-barcode, http://www.windytan.com/2016/02/barcode-recovery-using-priori.html

(Similar idea) [Finding CheckerBoard Points in opencv for any random ChessBoard( pattern size not known)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541683/finding-checkerboard-points-in-opencv-for-any-random-chessboard-pattern-size-no)

(Sort of but not really, and answer-less) [OpenCV find image frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720683/opencv-find-image-frequencies)

(Broad) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard_detection

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is:

1. Compute the [Scharr gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Alternative_operators) magnitude representations in both the x and y direction.
2. Subtract the y-gradient from the x-gradient. By performing this subtraction we are left with regions of the image that have high horizontal gradients and low vertical gradients.
3. Blur and threshold the image to filter out the noise.
4. Apply a closing kernel to the thresholded image to close the gaps between vertical stripes of the barcode.
5. Perform a series of dilations and erosions.
6. Find the largest contour in the image, which is now presumably the barcode.

More details and complete code can be found in [this PyImageSearch blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/24/detecting-barcodes-images-python-opencv/).

Comment: Thanks - I am not trying to do the full end-to-end barcode extraction, but rather to simply identify the best structuring element for restoring the pixels. NB also that the barcodes are 2D so x-y asymmetry is not necessarily expected.